# Create new many-to-many nested models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have a typical elementary problems which I cannot find a nice solution for. Let's take the typical many to many relationship in Rails, with the join table used to assign a value:

```
Recipe
    has_many :recipe_ingredients
    has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients

Ingredient
    has_many :recipe_ingredients
    has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_ingredients

RecipeIngredient
    belongs_to :recipe
    belongs_to :ingredient
    attr_accessible :quantity
```

Nothing strange here. Let's say now I want to to create a new recipe with new ingredients all in one go. I have some JSON sent to the server like this:

```
{"recipe"=>
    {"name"=>"New Recipe", 
     "ingredients"=>
        [{"name" => "new Ingr 1", "quantity"=>0.1},
         {"name" => "new Ingr 2", "quantity"=>0.7}]
    }
}
```

I reckon I can navigate the params and create the objects one by one but I was looking into leveraging the many-to-many association and above all the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, thus being able to do something like `Recipe.create(params[:recipe])` and have the object tree created for me. If that means changing the JSON being sent, it is not a problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON key should be `"ingredients_attributes"`:

```
Recipe
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
  attr_accessible :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients # note this
```

and

```
{"recipe"=>
  {"name"=>"New Recipe", 
    "ingredients_attributes"=>
      [{"name" => "new Ingr 1", "quantity"=>0.1},
       {"name" => "new Ingr 2", "quantity"=>0.7}]
  }
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to add `attr_accessible :ingredients` to the recipe model or else you'll end up with the error `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes`

Comment: You will need to do `attr_accessible: ingredients_attributes` as well (unless you alias the method, which I did, to keep the JSON key as it was). Anyway, this solves the problem but presents another problem when I want to create two recipes with the new ingredients shared between the recipes... I will have the same ingredient created twice, but I think in that case I will really have to navigate the params myself. :/